# Invisible autoloading in PhilePhP

Tags: php, autoload

I was just going through the code of PhileCMS and came across the following lines of code:

```
if (Registry::isRegistered('Phile_Settings')) {
    $config = Registry::get('Phile_Settings');
    if (!empty($config['base_url'])) {
        return $config['base_url'];
    }
}
```

The file can be seen **[HERE](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/blob/master/lib/Phile/Core/Router.php#L66)**

How come the static method of class `Registry` can be used here, when the file is not included or required at all? Is there some kind of auto loading going on in the backend that can't be seen? If so, what is this new kind of auto loading mechanism that has emerged?

Comment: Since this question is only related to PHP , i am adding no more framework tags !

Comment: ...yes?! Perhaps!? PHP does support autoloading, so it's not unreasonable to think that it's autoloading...!?

Comment: @deceze , i was more interested in what mechanism was being used to autoload .. i found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGSerlMoIrY , .. i beleive it is PSR 4 and composer . i am a newbie to server side so be gentle :)

Answer (score 1):

Read more about of classes autoloading in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

In PhileCMS the classes autoloading is confugired in the `Phile\Bootstrap::initializeAutoloader()` method (copy-paste of method body from the github for convinience):

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
// load phile core
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $fileName = LIB_DIR . str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    if (file_exists($fileName)) {
        require_once $fileName;
    }
});
// load phile plugins
spl_autoload_register('\Phile\Plugin\PluginRepository::autoload');
require(LIB_DIR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');
```

https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/blob/master/lib/Phile/Bootstrap.php#L93